# Use a Linked Service for configuring a BlobServiceClient

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I have been successfully using `BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string()` to obtain an instance of `BlobServiceClient`.   Our infrastructure also needs to be able to connect via  a `linked service`.  I did not see that capacity in the [BlobServiceClient API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python) .  How can that be done?

Linked services:  [Microsoft Learn for Linked Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-linked-services?tabs=data-factory)

Comment: Hi, @WestCoastProjects Could you please provide more information about what you mean by `linked service`?

Comment: @Venkatesan  Added link about `linked services` in `synapse` and `azure data factory`

Comment: Hi, @WestCoastProjects Are you running the code in the azure Synapse notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the connection from synapse linked service, use the below code in your synapse notebook.

```
# Get the connection string
import json
print(json.loads(mssparkutils.credentials.getPropertiesAll("Blob_LS"))['AuthKey'])

#Create instance from 
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
service = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://<storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net", credential=json.loads(mssparkutils.credentials.getPropertiesAll("<linked_service_name>"))['AuthKey'])
print("Instance created")


containers = service.list_containers(include_metadata=True)
for i in containers:
    print(i['name'])
```

**Output:**

[image]

**You can also get the connection string in normal python using the below REST API**.

```
GET {endpoint}/linkedservices/{linkedServiceName}?api-version=2020-12-01
```

Use the above REST API in python get request and get the required connection string from the JSON response. Check the [documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/synapse/data-plane/linked-service/get-linked-service?view=rest-synapse-data-plane-2020-12-01&tabs=HTTP#examples) for more information about it.